# How to test Entity classes from another Eclipse project in a Stateless Session Bean within a JUnit Test

Tags: unit-testing, junit, jpa-2.0, ejb-3.1, openjpa

So here's what I'm trying to do and stuck at:

I have a shared Eclipse Java project with @Entity (EJB 3.1) classes that is used by a couple of other Eclipse WebApp projects. This project itself has no persistence.xml! The other WebApp projects that use this project declare their own persistence.xml under WebContent/META-INF and refer to the JAR of this project in their persistence.xml using the jar-file tag. Of course the shared project's JAR is added as a deployment dependency in these WebApp projects and is placed under WEB-INF/lib.

Now I am creating JUnit4 Testcases to test Stateless session beans in these WebApp projects. I'm using Apache TomEE 1.5.0 Plus and in the testcase I use a @Before method to start the OpenEJB container in Embedded mode using EJBContainer.createEJBContainer() method. For this to work properly, I have created an alternate test.persistence.xml (that uses a different datasource to an HSQL memory db and creates the tables using forward mapping). I have placed this in META-INF of the src folder and in the @Before method, I set the "openejb.altdd.prefix" to "test" so that the alternate test.persistence.xml is read. All this setup is working.

The trouble is that as soon as OpenJPA 2.2.0 starts, it complains that there are no persistent classes from the shared project! This is because, the jar-file tag in test.persistence.xml refers to a jar that doesn't exist! When Eclipse deploys the other WebApp projects, it creates the JAR under WEB-INF/lib and the actual persistence.xml refers to the jar under that path! However, I do not find any such JAR when running a JUnit testcase.

So how do I refer to this JAR or the classes in the shared project in the test.persistence.xml without making the testcase itself overly dependent on deployment structure or any specific hard-coded path! This testcase will eventually be committed to the repository and hence must be such that any dev checking it out can simply run it.

Any pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

IMO the easiest and better way to do that is to use Arquillian.
It's far more easier to control the packaging, the life cycle of the container, etc
TomEE also provides a great integration (adapter) with Arquillian you can use.

Check the documentation page http://tomee.apache.org/documentation.html
There is an arquillian section.

You can also check TomEE examples page where you can find a huge amount of small samples including arquillian.

Hope it helps
Jean-Louis